# a custom comment box on emacs

Tags: emacs, macros

What would an Emacs macro look like which turns the following line:

```
# abc def
```

into:

```
#   +-------------+
#   |   abc def   |
#   +-------------+
```

?  The macro need not be general at all: It can hard code the box specs (i.e. 3 spaces before and after the comment, the frame characters  (`|`, `+`, `-` ), and assume that the comment is a one-liner.  It should, however, use whatever comment character is set for the current mode, and get the box length correct.

I'd also appreciate if you knew of an existing package which does this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what I think you want:

```
(defun box-comment-region (beg end)
  "do some fancy commenting"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (comment-region beg end -1)         ; first, uncomment
    (string-rectangle (point-min)
                      (progn (goto-char (point-max)) (line-beginning-position))
                      "  | ")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((max-len 0))
      (while (< (point) (point-max))
        (end-of-line)
        (setq max-len (max max-len (current-column)))
        (forward-line 1))
      (previous-line)
      (end-of-line)
      (insert (make-string (- max-len (current-column)) ?\ ))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (end-of-line)
      (insert (make-string (- max-len (current-column)) ?\ ))
      (end-of-line)
      (let ((top (point)))
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (previous-line)
        (end-of-line)
        (string-rectangle top (point) " | "))
      (let ((line-seg (concat "  +" (make-string (- max-len 2) ?-) "+ \n")))
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (insert line-seg)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (insert line-seg)))
    (comment-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`newcomment` has a function called `comment-box`, which produces a box comment consisting of the comment characters, i.e.:

```
###########
# abc def #
###########
```

or

```
/***********/
/* abc def */
/***********/
```

depending on the mode.  The only configurability it has is the number of characters to use for the box; for example in Lisp modes you end up with:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; abc def ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

The `comment-region-default` function should give you some idea of how to do comments.  `newcomment`'s comment styles aren't sufficiently flexible to implement what you want, so I think it'd be easiest to simply draw the box then add a regular (single or multiline, in languages where there is difference) comment to the region using the existing `newcomment` machinery.

Comment: Thanks for response. `newcomment`'s boxes are quite ugly, don't you think? :)  Quite inflexible indeed. So, unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Comment: I don't mind them, actually.  However, as I mentioned, its non-block comments will let you adapt to the current language's syntax, and its code can help you understand how to write what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called picture-mode, which might do something like that.

M-x picture-mode

Comment: I am not sure how this helps. The solution to be really effective should involve nothing more than a macro call, not going into a mode, drawing stuff, and back again.. unless you meant to suggest a specific function that this "package" provides..

Comment: ... that said, this picture mode is real cool in its own right. I didn't know about it, but quite useful indeed. +1 for that, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it was a long shot. I didn't know how often you needed to do this and why. Maybe picture-mode doesn't even do that. And thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[rebox2](https://github.com/lewang/rebox2/blob/master/rebox2.el) is the most comprehensive emacs box drawing extension.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
M-x comment-box
```

available as of Emacs 24.4 does this using point and mark as one would expect.